# Need to hide/remove zero line from chart js

Tags: javascript, php, charts

I am using chart JS I have used below code. I need to hide/remove only Zero line of X axis. Please check screenshot. https://prnt.sc/jco3y0

my code is

```
ar ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myMixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: chartData,
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            chartArea: {
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)'
            } ,              
            legend: {
                display: false
            } , 
            title: {
                display: true, 
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 10,
                        stepSize: 1,
                        fontColor : "#FFF",
                        fontSize : 20,
                        fontWeight:1000
                    },
                    gridLines:{
                        color: "#FFF",
                        lineWidth:3,
                        zeroLineColor :"#FFF",
                        zeroLineWidth : 2
                    },
                    stacked: true
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks:{
                        fontColor : "#FFF",
                        fontSize : 20,
                        fontWeight:1000
                    },
                    gridLines:{
                        color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, .1)",
                        lineWidth:5, 
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: true
            },

        }
```

My code is working but i am unable to remove Zero line of X axis.

Answer (score 0):

Change your minimum to 1.

```
ticks: {
        min: 1, // Change this
        max: 10,
        stepSize: 1,
        fontColor : "#FFF",
        fontSize : 20,
        fontWeight:1000
}
```

This is changing where the y-axis starts, and should remove the zero for you.

Another way to do this would be to increase all of your `chartData` by 1, as that would move it up a whole unit.

Comment: Not the cleanest solution, but it works for now. Thanks!